# Android Java Modifying Keyboard Keys

Tags: java, android, math, keyboard, key

After lots of searching I can not find any information about modifying the value given by a key on Android. My app has fields which should only be a valid number value (such as -1.9). So, instead of limiting it to integers only for input, I changed it so that the phone keypad would appear so users will not be able enter an invalid character.

The app will need to allow users to enter 'E' for large/small values (such as 5.9E-10).

Is it possible to modify the `space` button on the phone keypad to output 'E' into the text field and disable the symbols section button only for that particular page?

This would make it easy to input very large/small values and to get more accurate answers, since I use `bigDecimal`. The `mathContext` for number of decimal places is determined automatically by approximation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to modify the "space" button on the phone keypad to output 'E' into the text field and disable the symbols section button only for that particular page?

Only if you write your own input method editor, and then only if users elect to switch to your input method editor.

Or, do not use an `EditText`, but instead have your own calculator buttons as part of your own UI.

Comment: This isnt a normal calculator, its a calculator based on a given formula. There are a few text fields. I could make my own input part of the UI but how do i make the section to auto hide or appear just like a normal keyboard? And how to pass the value to the selected EditText without losing focus on it.